# Sharing drives to non domain users

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

we use our server only as a giant NAS drive for most users. So far I have been using Windows Professional on the client machines, but think this may be overkill. Can I share the drives to machines running WIndows 10 Home? If so, is that totally crazy unsafe?
Rgds
Petter

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Windows expert but I would say that it is indeed possible to make your shares accessible to non-domain users. But they would then need a local account on that server which might - and probably will - be different from the account on their local computer. Especially when they start changing the passwords on a semi-regular basis, both accounts - although they might have the same usersname - will have different passwords will will cause confusion with the users.

No, I do not believe this to be crazy or unsafe.